# How is Grassmann Algebra better than just using determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, clifford-algebras, grassmannian

I am reading Roger Penrose's road to reality. On page 209 ,210 he introduces the idea of Clifford algebra and how we can get back quarternion algebra by consideration of the 'second order' quantities in it. Right after that, something called Grassmann algebra is introduced in the following way:

> Finally, let me turn to Grassmann algebra. From the point of view of the above discussion, we may think of Grassmann algebra as a kind of degenrate case of Clifford algebra, where we have basic anticommuting generating elements $\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3...,\eta_n$ similar to $  \gamma_1, \gamma_2...,\gamma_n$ of the Clifford algebra, where each $\eta_s$ squares to zero, rather than to the $-1$ we have in the Clifford case
>
> The anticommutation law $\eta_p \eta_q = - \eta_q \eta_p$ holds as before , except that the Grassmann algebra is now more 'systematic' than the Clifford algebra, because we do not have to specify '$p \neq q$ in this equation.

What are the practical use of such Grassman algebra? At best, I am looking for illustrations where the above algebra laws can be used to solve problems in geometry or physics that the Gibbs school of mathematics (e.g., determinants) cannot or that the Gibbs school solves significantly more contortedly/incompletely.

In comment, some user had explained that it extends cross products and determinants. But, doesn't determinant itself already capture everything you need to capture with the determinant? What is use of another way of describing the same thing?

Comment: See wikipedia article on [the exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), e.g. the applications to physics and differential geometry.

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more simpler @Jan-MagnusØkland

Comment: You can think of $\wedge$ as a generalisation to $k^n$of the vector product $\times$ in ${\Bbb R}^3.$ See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/wedge-product-and-cross-product-any-difference)

Comment: @Buraian The determinant is $\epsilon_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$ is the dual basis to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The Grasmann algebra is used in formulation of the Stoke's theorem, which generalizes the classical Gauss, Green, Stoke's theorems to manifolds.

Comment: Ok, so this algebra is related to differential forms. But, in  differential form where do we see the basis squaring to zero thing?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910179/part-of-proof-that-d2-omega-0/910221#910221) is what your asking for?

Comment: “The neglect of the exterior algebra is the mathematical tragedy of our century.” –Gian-Carlo Rota, Indiscrete thoughts (1996)

Comment: I saw that, so the operator itself is the grassman algebra object? Also one more question, if it is same property as determinant, why not just use determinant?

Comment: Grassmann algebra says something about a $2\times 5$ matrix using determinants (all the $\binom 52$ minors). Not only square matrices like the usual determinant.

Comment: Grassmannian (manifold) is used to parametrize all the subspaces (of a fixed dimension) of a given vector space. It also makes an appearance in network coding (in that usually over a field of characteristic two), but admittedly it is only on the background there (IIRC).

Comment: Generally, the guidelines say that it is best to ask questions that have 1 answer, not an open-ended ad-infinitum sequence of various answers.

Comment: Would you agree that [a coordinate free description is better than a coordinate dependent one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21617)?

Comment: @Jan Magnud Okland thanks for the input. I'll check the link soon.

Comment: Bit beyond my level at the moment, I'll check it out again later